# PHP Secure Sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am currently developing a web application and I would like to make the user sessions as secure as I can.

I am currently using PHP's standard `$_SESSION` array for storing session data. I know that it stores a single cookie named `PHPSESSID` which is then looked up in the `$_SESSION` array however would adding a secondary cookie with a unique 'salt' value (for each session or user) which would then be compared with the one stored in the `$_SESSION` array make the session mechanism more secure?

Comment: In what way do you think it would make it more secure?

Comment: Well, I was thinking that it would make it much harder to hijack a session by guessing the session ID.

Comment: I am curious how you think someone would guess the session ID. Also if you salt it, you then need to adjust the session functions so they know how to find that and an algorithm to decode it so PHP knows what ID you passed back. Don't store sensitive data in the session.

Comment: Also welcome to SO - In the future it's better to present some code you're attempting use than just pose an open question like this.

Comment: That's not exactly what I mean. What I was thinking was having 2 cookies, one called PHPSSSID and the other one for example salt which would contain a salt value generated for the session. Then when PHP would find the session I would compare the salt value stored in the cookie with the one stored in the corresponding session. Edit: I have not yet implemented this, I just wanted to know whether it's worth spending time doing this.

Comment: The reason why I would like it to be really secure is because in this said web app there will be a variety of different users so I thought that I could store the user's ID in the session array and then when modifying something that belongs specifically to that user I would insert this ID in to the WHERE bit of the SQL statement. If the session was to be compromised it could allow the person to modify something that belongs to a different user.

Comment: Sessions are by default 26 characters long, each of which can be any of 36 characters from the set `a-z0-9`, that gives us a possible `29,098,125,988,731,506,183,153,025,616,435,000,000,000` (`36 ^ 26`) combinations, no one is going to brute force that by any conventional means.

Comment: So would you say that it would be _ok_ to use a user ID stored in the session variable to authenticate the user when performing actions (e.g. adding / deleting items)?

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help. I guess I was over-complicating the user authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Store your password session and cookie variables using one way encryption like md5. Adding an additional salt variable would not improve security as your primary concern would be your database being compromised.

Comment: Hi, I am currently using PHP 5.5 password_hash() and password_verify() functions. Would you say that I should also add a salt to this solution? If so should I store this variable in the database or generate it on the fly?

Comment: MD5 is not a suitable hashing algorithm as most hash's can be cracked now-a-days.